# How to report Likelihood Ratio as Chi2 / Δχ2 value

Tags: chi-squared-test, likelihood-ratio, growth-model

I'm comparing different models of a growth model using RStudio and the **anova(model1, model2)** command.

I get an output like (values completely random, just as example):

```
            Model   df   AIC     BIC    logLik  Test   L.Ratio   p-value
model1        1     3    420     435     -265
model2        2     4    410     420     -253   1vs2    16.118    .002
```

I have to report the results as a Δχ2 value. How do I get from the given Likelihood Ratio to Δχ2?

I know the L.Ratio is given under a Chi2 distribution – but does it need to be transformed and what happens to the df?

Thank you!
Carlos

Comment: The likelihood ratio is your $\chi^2$ statistic and the $df$ of the test can be found from the difference between the $df$ of each model.

Comment: Hi Matt! Thanks for your fast answer. So in my given example, this would be reported as following, correct?

Δχ2(1) = 16.118, p = .002

Comment: Yes that is correct